# linetype manual change in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Having the dataset `iris` as an example:

How it is possible to add these 3 lines into the leggend?

```
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Petal.Width)) +
  geom_line(aes(color="line"),lty=4) +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept=1, color="abline"),lty = 1) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ x, se = F, aes(color = "Trend"),lty=3)
```

At this example the legend linetypes doesnt match with the plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of setting the linetypes as arguments map on the `linetype` aes. Here you can simply use the labels you used for `color`. The linetypes can then be set via `scale_linetype_manual`. Additonally give "both" legends the same name via e.g. `labs` so that they get merged into one. Finally use `show.legend=FALSE` in `geom_smooth` (Otherwise each legend key will get an additional line glyph reflecting the trend line).

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Petal.Width)) +
  geom_line(aes(color="line", lty = "line")) +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept=1, color="abline", lty = "abline")) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ x, se = F, aes(color = "Trend", lty = "Trend"), show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c(line = 4, abline = 1, Trend = 3)) +
  labs(color = "color", linetype = "color")
```

[image]